# How can i replace a listView item with a string after the operation on the item has ended?

Tags: c#, listview

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView.Items.Count > 0)
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

In the DoWork i resize number of images files and save them to the hard disk and also reporting percentages and the number of images. In the ProgressChanged event i'm updating a progressBar and some labels.

```
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++)
            {
                BitmapImage imagetosave = ResizeImage(directories[i]);
                Save(imagetosave, saveDirectory);

                int percents = ((i + 1) * 100) / directories.Count;
                worker.ReportProgress(percents, i);
            }
        }

        private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            label.Content = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
            label2.Content = e.UserState;
        }

        private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

What i want to do is each time image was resized and then saved to the hard disk change the item text in the listView to "Resized and saved" and maybe even to color the item for example in green.

This is how i resize the images and save them:

```
public void Save(BitmapImage image, string filePath)
        {
            BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));

            using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                encoder.Save(fileStream);
            }
        }

        private BitmapImage ResizeImage(string file)
        {
            var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            var stream = File.OpenRead(file);
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmap.DecodePixelHeight = 100;
            bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
            bitmap.EndInit();
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();

            return bitmap;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your background worker finished you call back into the UI thread and run this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new RefreshCallback(Refresh));
```

Where `RefreshCallback` is a simple delegate of your `Refresh` function which updates the list items.